# How can I find which Shard is over 30Gb in Elasticsearch 6.3

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

I'd like to know if there is a DSL query that I can run to get a list of those Shards that are over a certain size?

The _cat/shards lists them all, but we have thousands of shards and even exporting them all to Excel and trying to filter out by value is proving difficult.

Can we specify a Query to extract those shards that are greater than 30Gb?

Answer (score 5):

You can display all shards and sort them by size. According to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/cat.html#sort):

> Each of the commands accepts a query string parameter s which sorts the table by the columns specified as the parameter value. Columns are specified either by name or by alias, and are provided as a comma separated string. By default, sorting is done in ascending fashion. Appending :desc to a column will invert the ordering for that column. :asc is also accepted but exhibits the same behavior as the default sort order.

So you can list all shards by size in descending order with:

```
GET _cat/shards?v&s=store:desc
```

The `v` is for the [verbose command](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat.html#verbose). The `s`is for the [sort query string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat.html#verbose). `store` is the name of the column containing shards sizes and `:desc` is for sorting in descending order.

All shards greater than 30Gb will appear first.